# jQuery events being triggered more than once

Tags: ajax, events, event-handling, jquery

I have a table where some data is displayed to the user. There are buttons for CRUD'ing the data, and I use jQuery on the front end. When a button is pressed, a modal is displayed and the data is updated via an ajax request.

My problem is: if I click on an update button, close the modal, click on another update button and update the data, it saves the same new data on **every** clicked row. In short, my code is being executed multiple times, as many as the number of clicks I performed.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/QWQHM6aW

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*--------------------------------------------*/
    //  GENERAL
    /*--------------------------------------------*/
    function loadingStart() {
        $("#overlay").show(); 
        $("#loading").show();
    }

    function loadingDone() {
        $("#overlay").hide(); 
        $("#loading").hide();
    }

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        loadingDone();
        //alert('Ajax Terminou');
    });

    function reloadRows() {
        $.post("ajax.php", { type: "AllRows" }) // Faz um post do tipo AllRows.
         .done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            //$("#tbody").html(data);
         });
    }
    $("body").on("click", ".update-socio-btn", updateSocio);
    /*--------------------------------------------*/
    // UPDATE
    /*--------------------------------------------*/
    function updateSocio(event) {
        $("#socio-form input").val(''); // Apagar os valores do form.
        loadingStart(); // Começar o Loading...
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id-holder').html(); // Pegar o valor do id holder e salvar na var id.
        $("#socio-form input").removeClass("input-transparent").prop("disabled", false); // Queremos ver e utilizar os inputs.
        $(".modal-footer").removeClass("hidden"); // Queremos ver o footer do modal.
        $(".btn-modal").attr("id", "update-btn-confirm"); // Atribui o id: update-btn-confirm ao .btn-modal.

        $.post("ajax.php", { type: "read", id: id }) // Faz um post do tipo Read e retorna os valores nos inputs correspondentes
         .done(function(data) {
            console.log('read');
            jsonOBJ = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var key in jsonOBJ) {
                $("input[name=" + key + "]").val(jsonOBJ[key]);
            }
         });

        $("#update-btn-confirm").click(function() { // Quando clicar no botão de salvar.
            var formArray = $("#socio-form").serializeArray(); // Pega todas as informações dos inputs e transforma em um array json.
            $.post("ajax.php", { type: "update", id: id, inputs: formArray }) // Faz um post do tipo Update.
             .done(function(data) {
                console.log('uptade');
                alert(data);
                event.stopPropagation();
             });
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I strongly suspect the issue lies on the `.on` method, but I'm having a hard time pinpointing it. I know I can use `.live()` or `.bind()`, but I'm trying to avoid it as both are deprecated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you click the element with class `.update-socio-btn`, the `updateSocio` function is run. Every time `updateSocio` is run, a new click event is bound on `#update-btn-confirm`.

You can fix this by moving the click binding outside of the `updateSocio` function and only binding the event handler once.